# Java stream: How to map to a single item when using groupingBy instead of to list

Tags: java, java-stream

Given an order class like:

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
static class Order {
    long customerId;
    LocalDate orderDate;
}
```

and a list of orders:

```
List<Order> orderList = List.of(new Order(1, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(1, LocalDate.of(2021,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(1, LocalDate.of(2022,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(2, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(2, LocalDate.of(2021,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(3, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(3, LocalDate.of(2022,Month.APRIL,21)),
                                new Order(4, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)));
```

I need to get a list of `customerId` where last `orderDate` is older than 6 months. So for above example `[2,4]`. My idea is to first to group by `customerId`, second map to last `orderDate` and third to filter those which are older than 6 months. I am stuck at second step on how to map to a single order with the recent `orderDate`

First step

```
Map<Long, List<Order>> grouped =
        orderList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomerId));
```

Second step (stuck here how to change the above to get only one item as value)

```
Map<Long, Order> grouped =
        orderList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomerId, ???));
```

or even better

```
Map<Long, LocalDate> grouped =
        orderList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomerId, ???));
```

I have tried to use `Collectors.mapping()` , `Collectors.reducing()` and `Collectors.maxBy()` but having a lot of compile errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap` collector to have a map of listed orders by customer id. After that, you can filter only those orders which are older than 6 months.

See the implementation below:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

```java
public static List<Long> getCustomerIdsOfOrdersOlderThanSixMonths(final List<Order> orderList) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(orderList)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .stream()
            .filter(o -> Objects.nonNull(o) && Objects.nonNull(o.getOrderDate()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  Order::getCustomerId,
                  Function.identity(),
                  BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Order::getOrderDate))))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getOrderDate()
                  .plusMonths(6)
                  .isBefore(ChronoLocalDate.from(LocalDate.now())))
            .map(Order::getCustomerId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

```java
List<Long> customerIds = getCustomerIdsOfOrdersOlderThanSixMonths(orderList);
// [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupingBy()` with a downstream `maxBy()` collector, and then filter the results to just those dates that are older than six months:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    private record Order(long customerId, LocalDate orderDate) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Order> orderList =
            List.of(new Order(1, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(1, LocalDate.of(2021,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(1, LocalDate.of(2022,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(2, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(2, LocalDate.of(2021,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(3, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(3, LocalDate.of(2022,Month.APRIL,21)),
                    new Order(4, LocalDate.of(2020,Month.APRIL,21)));

        final LocalDate sixMonthsAgo = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(6);

        List<Order> mostRecentOrders =
            orderList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::customerId,
                                           Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Order::orderDate))))
            .values().stream()
            .filter(opt -> opt.filter(o -> o.orderDate().isBefore(sixMonthsAgo)).isPresent())
            .map(Optional::orElseThrow)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(oldOrders);
    }
}
```

outputs

```
[Order[customerId=2, orderDate=2021-04-21], Order[customerId=4, orderDate=2020-04-21]]
```

First you get a map of customer ids and (Wrapped in an `Optional` due to the way `Collectors.maxBy()` works) the most recent order by date. Then filter out the entries where that most recent date is within the last six months. Then extract the remaining orders from the `Optional`s and return them in a `List`. If you just want the customer IDs and don't care about the rest of the `Order` object, modify the final `map()` and returned type appropriately.

Comment: (Using Java 17 records for sake of demonstration)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach on doing this.  Use `Collectors.partioningBy` to segregate the dates. Set up a couple variables to help keep things straight in the partitioning and printing process.

```
static boolean WITHIN_LAST_SIX_MONTHS = false;
static boolean BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO = true;
```

- partition the Order based on if it was issued before 6 months ago (true) or within the last 6 months (false).
- then map the Order to just the `CustomerId` and return as a `Set` (no need for duplicates)
- And that's it.

```
Map<Boolean, Set<Long>> result = orderList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                        order -> order.getOrderDate()
                                .isBefore(LocalDate.now()
                                        .minusMonths(6)),
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                Order::getCustomerId,
                                Collectors.toSet())));

System.out.println("BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO="+result.get(BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO));
System.out.println("WITHIN_LAST_SIX_MONTHS="+result.get(WITHIN_LAST_SIX_MONTHS));
```

prints

```
BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO=[1, 2, 3, 4]
WITHIN_LAST_SIX_MONTHS=[1, 3]
```

Now just remove those ID's of recent orders from those that occurred over six months ago.

```
result.get(BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO).removeAll(result.get(WITHIN_LAST_SIX_MONTHS));
System.out.println(result.get(BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO));
```

prints

```
[2, 4]
```

Note that the final set could be returned directly from the `stream` by using `collectingAndThen` for the partitioning collector. The finisher would look like this.

```
thismap -> {
    Set<Long> retSet = new HashSet<>(thismap.get(BEFORE_SIX_MONTHS_AGO));
    retSet.removeAll(thismap.get(WITHIN_LAST_SIX_MONTHS));
    return retSet;
}
```

But imo, this is rather busy and actually complicates matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Collectors.toMap* with a *mergeFunction* for your step 2:

```
 Map<Long, LocalDate> latestOrderByCustomer = 
            orderList.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Order::customerId, 
                                                Order::orderDate, 
                                                (order1, order2) -> order1.isAfter(order2) ? order1 : order2));
```